# How to unmasrshal json in this case?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have to unmarshal Json(Request, Response Body) in echo framework midleware for ELK, like this code.

```
var reqJSONBody, resJSONBody map[string]interface{}
if len(*reqBody) > 0 {
    if err := unmarshalJSON(reqBody, &reqJSONBody); err != nil {
        gl.ServiceLogger.Error("error parsing the request body: ", requestURI, err)
    }
    encryptPrivacyField(&reqJSONBody)
}
if len(*resBody) > 0 && resContentType != "" && strings.Contains(resContentType, "application/json") {
    if err := unmarshalJSON(resBody, &resJSONBody); err != nil {
        gl.ServiceLogger.Error("error parsing the response body: ", requestURI, err)
    }
    encryptPrivacyField(&resJSONBody)
}
```

And it is work,

But, Some URI response to `[]map[string]interface{}` type.

So I got this error.

`json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}`

What is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Best way is to use concrete types and a custom unmarshaler. The quickest way however would be to unmarshal into `interface{}`/`any`, e.g. `var resJSONBody any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing:

```
var reqJSONBody, resJSONBody interface{}
if len(*reqBody) > 0 {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(*reqBody, &reqJSONBody); err != nil {
        gl.ServiceLogger.Error("error parsing the request body: ", requestURI, err)
    }
    encryptPrivacyField(&reqJSONBody)
}
```

So I have to change `encryptPrivacyField` method like this:

```
func encryptPrivacyField(data *interface{}) {
switch reflect.TypeOf(*data).Kind() {
case reflect.Map:
    for _, field := range getPrivacyFieldList() {
        if item, ok := (*data).(map[string]interface{})[field]; ok && item != nil {
            (*data).(map[string]interface{})[field] = db.NewEncString(fmt.Sprintf("%v", (*data).(map[string]interface{})[field]))
        }
    }

    for _, field := range getHashFieldList() {
        if item, ok := (*data).(map[string]interface{})[field]; ok && item != nil {
            (*data).(map[string]interface{})[field] = db.NewHashString(fmt.Sprintf("%v", (*data).(map[string]interface{})[field]))
        }
    }
case reflect.Slice:
    for index, _ := range (*data).([]interface{}) {
        encryptPrivacyField(&(*data).([]interface{})[index])
    }

}
}
```

Thanks to @mkopriva for the advice.